# Are these functions negligible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science, cryptography

I am a bit new to and have currently starting to learn cryptography. I am referring the book 'Introduction to Modern Cryptography' and some other blogs and texts. A concept which I am studying but not able to get full feel of is negligible functions. I have got some understanding of it but its not enough to go in-depth. Regarding the same I am solving this question where I have to prove these functions as negligible or not.

1. $n^{-c}$
2. $c^{-\log\log n}$

where $c$ is a constant. Can someone please show me how to approach the proof step by step so that I could use the same understanding in other examples and concepts. I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give your definition of "negligible"? Typically this is a relative concept, one function is negligible relative to another one. For example $1$ is negligible relative to $n$ in the limit $n \to \infty$. (The limit being $n \to \infty$ is so common in computer science that it's rarely stated explicitly).

Comment: No function by itself is "negligible". You are probably looking at a situation where you have a sum of two functions where for large input values the second is much smaller than the first. Then in that context it will be "negligible". If you [edit] the question to provide more context perhaps we can help. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: For positive $xc$ both of these functions approach $0$ as $n$ grows. That may help you - depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of cryptography, negligible usually means that it is negligeable compared to the reciprocal of any polynomial. See definition 2.4 here for the precise meaning: https://intensecrypto.org/public/lec_02_computational-security.html#the-asymptotic-approach

The reason why the class of polynomial function is taken is because the usual model of 'efficient' computation refers to polynomial time algorithms. If some error decays faster than $1/p(n)$ for any $p(n)$, asymptotically it will be invisible to a fixed polynomial time algorithm. For instance, if the probability of some secret being leaked in negligible, a polynomial time adversary cannot just repeat an experiment until the secret is leaked.

For example, $n^{-c}$ is not negligible. This is because it does not shrink faster than $n^{-c - 1}$, as $n^{-c} \geq n^{-c -1}$ for $n \geq 1$.

For analyzing the other function, try taking log.